# Azure ML Dataset Versioning: What is Different if it Points to the Same Data?

Tags: azure, version, azure-synapse, azure-machine-learning-service

**Context**

In AzureML, we are facing an error when running a pipeline. It fails on `to_pandas_dataframe` because a particular dataset "could not be read beyond end of stream". On its own, this seems to be an issue with the parquet file that is being registered, maybe special characters being misinterpreted.

However, when we explicitly load a previous "version" of this Dataset--which points to the exact same location of data--it works as expected. In the documentation ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-version-track-datasets#versioning-best-practice)), Azure says that "when you load data from a dataset, the current data content referenced by the dataset is always loaded." This makes me think that a new version of the dataset with the same schema will be, well, the same.

**Questions**

1. What makes a Dataset version *different* from another version when both point to the same location? Is it only the schema definition?
2. Based on these differences, is there a way to figure out why one version would be succeeding and another failing?

**Attempts**

- The schemas of the two versions are identical. We can profile both in AzureML, and all the fields have the same profile information.

Comment: thanks for the detailed write up! if what you're saying is true, this is definitely a bug with the SDK. You should def open a support ticket with MSFT and I'll expect they'll want your parquet file to experiment with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rightly suggested by @Anand Sowmithiran in comment section, This looks more like a bug with the SDK.

You can raise [Azure support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/)

Comment: Yeah, seems to be the case. I've moved on from this particular issue, but I will pass it on.