# What is the importance of Azure ML dataset versioning?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I created an Azure ML dataset with a single file inside a storage blob container. Azure ML studio portal then showed 1 file in the dataset version 1.

I wanted to add 2 more files and create a new dataset version. So I copied 2 more files to the same blob container folder. Surprisingly even before I created a new dataset version, the ML studio portal UI shows the number of files in the same dataset as 3. (image below).

I then went through Azure ML [versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-version-track-datasets) docs which tell datasets are just references to original data. I also see a suggestion to create new folders for new data and I agree that the new files were not copied to a new folder here as recommended.

But still, the metadata (e.g. files in dataset, total size of dataset etc) of a previously created dataset version is getting updated. What is the importance of Azure ML dataset versioning if **metadata** of dataset version itself is being updated?

[image]

<sub>A related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70380861) was in SO, but closed as a bug.</sub>

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this problem?

Comment: No. I did not find.

Answer (score 0):

Versioning will improve the accuracy of the model. Based on the data extracted we can perform the prediction model running on different versions of the dataset. The dataset may consist of the same name, but the version will contain different values. This supports the parallel execution of the models on the same storage account support.

We can create different Auto ML prediction models with different versions of the dataset.

[image]

[image]

The two versions are uploaded to the same blobstorage and now using any one of the version, I will run the prediction model (Classification).

[image]

The above screen is of churn_analysis running as the Auto ML prediction model, running with 25% of testing and 75% of training the dataset. The Version of the dataset used in this prediction model is mentioned in the below image.

[image]

In the same manner we can do the prediction model with different versions of the training and test set splits and also the type of model for each version can be chosen. We will get different models result on the single dataset for better understanding of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed writeup. But, I felt it is more generic explanation of what is versioninig. The point I am raising is, try modifying your churn.csv file now, then the `total size of files in dataset` field in version 1 and version 2 will change. I understand Azure ML doesn't keep extra copy and it is reference. But why version **metadata** itself is changing leaving no clue of change. This give wrong impression to user that nothing in dataset has changed since it was created and we could create a new experiment to create same model all over again.